# Displaying a progressbar or error message in a fancybox

Tags: javascript

Here is what I have in my member.php for my fancybox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
            $("a#uploadpage").fancybox({
                'titleShow'     : false
            });
    });
</script>
.
.
.
<a id="uploadpage" href='uploadpage.php'>Change Image</a> <br/>
```

This works perfectly, and by perfectly I mean it opens the fancybox containing the php code in uploadpage.php. Once the user pushes the submit button in uploadpage.php to upload there image I want it to either display an error message(invalid file type or file size too big), or a progressbar if the image is a valid file type and below 1MB. How do I do this within the **SAME FANCYBOX**? (I have the code for the error messages and progressbar already so I just need to know how to either refresh the fancybox or how to use javascript to accomplish this.)

Thanks a lot, I greatly appreciate it.
-Matt

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, I've never used fancybox the way you are trying to use it, but, here's my suggestion: you could try using a class name instead of an ID. The anchor would be `<a class="uploadpage" ...>` instead of the id you use now.  Also, change

```
$("a#uploadpage").fancybox({
```

to

```
$("a.uploadpage").fancybox({
```

fancybox makes a new instance of the box for each invokation when using id. It tries to reuse it if you use class names instead. Also, could try marking with a `rel="myuploadbox"`, i.e.

```
<a rel="myuploadbox" class="uploadpage" ...>
```

Fancybox uses the `rel` attribute to group related things together, this might keep it from closing the box on your submit. Also, wrap everything you want inside that same fancybox in a `div` tag with the same `rel` attribute (I don't know if it would be supported that way by fancybox.. give it a try).